# Handling animations multiple objects in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

Working on an Angular app that will be working with quite a lot of Modals in a wizard style configuration.

I'm using the Angular-cli to make the project.

Here is how I'm setting my animations:

```
  animations:[
    trigger('right-center-left',[
      state('right', style({
          transform: 'translateX(100%)'
      })),
      state('center', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0)',
      })),
      state('left', style({
        transform: 'translateX(-100%)',
      })),
      transition('right => center', animate('300ms ease-in')),
      transition('center => left', animate('300ms ease-in')),
    ]),
  ],
```

I have five divs that have a class of `.modal` that I will be transitioning through. There is a button that calls `nextModal()` and another that calls `prevModal()`. What I'm trying to do is when `nextModal()` is called, the current modal slides away, and the next one slides in. The reverse is true of the `prevModal()` function on the controller.

I've already tested using this type of call inside the template:

```
<button class='right-btn' (click)='prevModal(addressModal,phonesModal)'>Previous</button>
<button class='left-btn' (click)='nextModal(phonesModal, emailModal)'>Next Part</button>
```

and here are my modal change functions:

```
  nextModal = (current, next) => {
    current = 'left';
    next = 'center';
  }
  prevModal = (prev, current) => {
    prev = 'center';
    current = 'right';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

call with template decorator on element

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [@right-center-left]="hero.state"
    (click)="hero.toggleState()">
  {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

p.s. I think can be error by name, change on RightCenterLeft or any animation name, in example - SlideAnimation.